# Sequelize.js eager loading in many-to-many table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables, Users and MControllers. They have a many-to-many relationship through another table called History, defined like:

```
var History = sequelize.define("History", {
id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
message: {
  type : DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull : false
}
}, {
timestamps: true,
updatedAt: false,
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
  }
}
});
```

I have made the association like:

```
MController.belongsToMany(User, {through: History, onDelete: 'cascade' });
User.belongsToMany(MController, {through: History, onDelete: 'cascade' });
```

Now, I need to query the History table with an eager-loading with the User table. Something like this:

```
historyEntity.findAll({
        where : {
            MControllerId : mcontrollerId
        },
        include : {
            model : this.User
        }
    });
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
[Error: User is not associated to History!]
```

If I inspect the History model, it really doesn't have any associations.
How can I make this query possible?

EDIT:
I tried to query the Users table, with eager-loading the History table, without success. It tells me that Users is not associated with Histories, fact that is not true since I have inspected the User model and it says:

```
{ History: [Object],
    UserMController: [Object],
    OauthAccessTokensUsers: [Object],
    OauthRefreshTokensUsers: [Object] },
```

Answer (score 1):

After discussing your needs @Renan, I'd recommend to associate the `User` model to `MController` twice, one as `User` and one as `Activator`.

```
// normal users
MController.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'MControllerUsers', onDelete: 'cascade' });
User.belongsToMany(MController, {through: 'MControllerUsers', onDelete: 'cascade' });

// activator users
MController.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'MControllerActivators', onDelete: 'cascade', as: 'Activator' });
User.belongsToMany(MController, {through: 'MControllerActivators', onDelete: 'cascade', as: 'Activator' });
```

This way you can have the same model `User`linked to `MController` and having two different roles, allowing you to have many `User`s and `Activator`s per MController

Answer (score 0):

Watching your associations, why do you have `models.User` and in other places only `User`? Check if that fixes something.

If not, I've work around this using

`History.hasOne(MController);
History.hasOne(User);`

Comment: I edited my code for the question. In all the places I use models.User. Besides that, putting hasOne, like you said, will add a fk in the User table. Not what I want, since History is a many-to-many table. Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: yes, as you're explaining it, History is working as the join table between Users and MControllers, can you explain what you're trying to achieve? because with those associations History is NOT a many-to-many table

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong. I have a User table, and a MController table. They are related by another join table called UserMController. All is working fine, but now I need another table to tell which User activated some MController. So I thought about a History table, that would have a two fk, UserId and MControllerId, and the message I want to store. So I tried to make those associations, without success.

Comment: ok, a User has many MControllers and a MController has many Users, as far as I understand, a MController is activated by a single User?

Comment: At a time, yes. But a MController can be activated by multiple users in his lifetime. Don't know I was clear

Comment: yes, you can link the same User model to MController twice, using 'as': 'Activators' option, if I'm not clear enough I can post another answer, but father's day so will be til midnight